# Using SVG, hover on X, Y or Z to make X and Z rotate

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, snap.svg

I have an element (logo) on my webpage which contains three other elements, I want to make it so when the logo as a whole is hovered, two of the elements within the logo (two of the letters) will rotate around their centre indefinitely.

I have achieved rotating elements with CSS animations, but only to get an element to rotate when itself is hovered. I cannot figure out how to get multiple elements to rotate when any of the three elements are hovered using CSS.

I have the three elements in their own svg tags as data URI, all within a single g, which itself is in an a href that links to the home page.

```
<header><a id="logoLink" href="">

<g class="logoSvg">

<svg id="c" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 34.68 37.2"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:#e94a4a;}</style></defs><title>logo</title><path class="cls-1" d="...
</svg>
<svg id="hri" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 76.88 79.53"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:#e94a4a;}</style></defs><title>logo copy</title><path class="cls-1" d="M
</svg>
<svg id="s" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 31.19 37.2"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:#e94a4a;}</style></defs><title>logo copy 2</title><path class="cls-1" d="M
</svg>

</g>

</a>
```

In the html doc I also have a script source with SnapSVG content, as well as linking to the SnapSVG source code:

```
<script src="js/logoAni.js"></script>
```

The SnapSVG js is as follows:

```
var logo = $("#logoSvg");
var c = $("#c");
var hri = $("#hri");
var s = $("#s");

function rollover(){
    c.transform('r0,100,100');
    c.animate({transform: "r360,100,100"},1000,mina.linear,anim);
    s.transform('r0,100,100');
    s.animate({transform: "r360,100,100"},1000,mina.linear,anim);
}

logo.hover(rollover);
```

I'm assuming that the snap code is wrong. Perhaps I don't need to use snap at all?

Update:
Here's a recent jfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Lc12bvyn/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rollover code itself looks ok (assuming missing code is, if you still get stuck I would put up a jsfiddle or jsbin), it's just applying to the wrong type of elements.

I'm guessing you are using jquery for the selections? If so, I'm not sure that will work..rather than doing..

```
var logo = $("#logoSvg");
```

try

```
var logo = Snap("#logoSvg");
```

That way you will get the Snap element (which links to the DOM element) to operate on, not a DOM or jquery object.

You can't transform the 'svg' element itself typically (as it doesn't technically support the transform attribute as far as I'm aware).

So, I would put the two svgs you want to transform inside a g/group element and transform that g element. You could look into css, but css transforms on svg don't always play nice regarding browser support, so whilst Davids answer may be good for normal elements, I'm not sure it would play nice for svg elements (especially rotations), do test different browsers very early if you do try that method.

Comment: Still having troubles, heres my js fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/Lc12bvyn/

Trying to rotate the C and S

Comment: Just your selector is the issue, you already have a path, so you don't need to create a new one with path(). So Snap(somePathSelector) will work alone... https://jsfiddle.net/ian_b/Lc12bvyn/4/

Answer (score 0):

You could use [@keyframes animation](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp) and nested styles in SCSS to achieve something like this without javascript. Not sure if you're wanting to go this route, but it seems the most straightforward to me.

Particularly you're looking to set the `animation-iteration-count` to infinite on the elements that you want to rotate.

The below code is just some rough concept stuff, not sure the animation you're looking to set, or the full context of your elements, etc.

```
.logoSvg {

  &:hover {

    &:first-child {
      animation-name: someAnimation;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    }

    &:last-child {
      animation-name: someAnimation;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    }
  }
}

@keyframes someAnimation {
  0%: {transform: some transformation};
  100%: {transform: some transformation};
}
```

I hope this is helpful Chris, or at least gets you going in the right direction.